# Padding Left quirk in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/hERrX/

```
input{
    padding:1%;
}
input#checking{
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

Please Check the above link in FIREFOX and help me with the problem. It seems to work quite well in Chrome. The padding-left doesn't seem to work even though it has higher priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you don't use a `%` length:

http://jsfiddle.net/hERrX/15/

```
input{
    padding: 5px;
}
input#checking{
    padding-left: 40px
}
```

I don't know *why* it doesn't work with `%`..

I found an existing bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527459

Comment: i know tat. but any workaround. coz im depending on fluid layout which uses % a lot.

Comment: Maybe you could use `em` sizes for paddings etc. However that relates to the element font size, not the container dimensions. Or consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @Shahal Tharique: With some inspiration from @-Flambino and @-Eric, this is a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/rJhzB/. Tested in IE7-9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

Comment: @thirtydot: but once the text goes beyond the text box width it's not working.

Comment: @Shahal Tharique: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want there to *always* be a `40px` space on the left, even when the text is very long?

Comment: @Shahal: Fluid layouts don't need to imply fluid padding.

Answer (score 2):

This looks similar to question [#1446832](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446832/form-input-wont-take-percentage-padding), Firefox seems to not work too well with percentage paddings.

The generic `padding: 1%` is conflicting with the specific left-padding `padding-left: 40px`. In jsfiddle.net I fixed it by replacing the latter with `padding: 0 0 0 40px`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-indent: 40px` instead. That works in Firefox

Comment: @thirtydot: It does once you add some text.

Comment: @Eric: You're right, I didn't notice that - the jumping caret fooled me.

Comment: Heh, that's a strange little bug. I just ran a jsfiddle where there was already text in the field, so I didn't notice it